# When we don't have define Operator+ as friend? C++

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

I read in some sources that if we implements `operator+` by `operator=+` so we don't have define `operator+` as "friend".

Someone can explain it?

Comment: This question might be qualified as too broad and less suitable for this site. Check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for future guidelines.

Comment: Why don't you try it? Also, why use "friend" at all? That should put you on track for finding out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea is to avoid duplicate code. See this example:

```
class A
{
    int a = 0;

public:
    A & operator+=(const A& other) { a += other.a; return *this; }
};
```

Then you could implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=` saving yourself the duplicate code, and keeping it as a free function:

```
A operator+(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) { A tmp(lhs); tmp += rhs; return tmp; }
```

Which means you now have two functions. And if you change the meaning of `+=`, the meaning of `+` changes too. Easier to maintain.

Comment: Another advantage is that it allows something like `2 + foo`, assuming `foo` has an implicit conversion to say `int`. But don't see in your example why this would avoid copying code. Cannot you just do the same with a member function?

Comment: Yes, you get the ordering for free by doing that, which is nice. You get that for it just being a non-member function :D

Comment: Tiny bug: `lhs` is const ref, so the code shouldn't compile.

Comment: @Carl Can you explain what was the error in your first answer? and how you fixed it?

Comment: @juanchopanza Woops, thanks for pointing that out. @AskMath You can't change a `const` parameter since it's constant.

Comment: Another tiny bug: now you pass not const reference to operator+, which should not modify its operands.

Comment: @juanchopanza You have idea how to fix it?

Comment: @Carl `tmp` don't deleted in the ending of the method (as automatic variable)?

Comment: @AskMath You don't need to manually `delete tmp;` as it was not dynamically allocated on the heap.

Comment: @Carl it's not like this code? : `int func(){ int x=3; return x; }` ?

Comment: @AskMath In that example the compiler is likely to optimize the construction and destruction away and just return `x` directly. Not sure if I understand what you're asking?

Comment: @Carl ohhh I am sorry, I thought in firslty that it's like that: `int* func() {int x=3; return &x;}` . But it's not. Yeah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172356/discussion-between-carl-and-askmath).